# Dart Polymer white screen of death?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a project that works fine when I view as Javascript but when I boot it in Dartium nothing is shown. There is no errors either. I am not sure what I have done. Even other projects that haven't had their code touched for weeks no longer can be view in Dartium so I assume it's a dodgy package but pubspec only uses browser, polymer, tweenengine.

Thoughts?

Comment: Also, when I make a new polymer dart project (with Dart Editor), the click counter module does not show!

Comment: I updated to the latest SDK and Editor and the app works fine.

I do need the older SDK (as I need IE9 support) so not ideal for now but I can build in the latest and compile to js using the old

Answer (score 0):

I also had that problem yesterday. Deleting Dart Editor + Dartium and installing it again, fixed it for me. A Friend also had that problem, reinstalling also fixed it for him.